# asp.net Custom Server Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking to build a custom control, or a custom server control that will allow anyone that uses this control to be able to amend the look and feel of it similar to the way you can customise the asp.net membership login controls.

I have tried to do some research into this, but nothing I have found gives me what I am looking for.

I can find stuff that allows me to use templates like the datalist, or a repeater, but nothing that says this control has a textbox and a button and allows the person using the control to dictate what markup goes around these buttons.

Can anyone give me any pointers on where to look or what to google?

This is an example of the login control being customisable, where although username and password is added to the control, it hooks up behind the scens to the one that would display by default: [Customise Login Control Layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.layouttemplate.ASPX)

Thanks

Comment: I would look into XSLT for this, the use of different XSLT templates can get you markup variations you want while still having the core controls in the final result.

Comment: Ideally I would like this to be able to be dropped on the page or user control from the toolbox, and allow someone to manipulate this in the exact same way as you can with the asp.net login control.

Comment: It has to be a server control. To develop it, you need 2 instances of visual studio open. First one is your development / project. Second one will actually be the one where you drop the dll and put your control in the designer. Then, attach to process from first VS to second VS. At that point, you can play with VisualStudio.Designer namespace classes to see what you can do and how flexible you can make it. The designer is generally a piece of crap, so I expect what you want to do will take a lot of effort and lots of workarounds / hacks. Particularly depending on how flexible you want it to be

Comment: If you think about it, you're almost trying to build a designer within the designer for your custom server control...

Comment: I want to be able to use it like thie following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.layouttemplate.ASPX

Comment: This might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478964.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Costume Controls](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_custom_controls.htm)

This the best tutorial i had seen over the internet that guide you to create your own costume control

Comment: I will check this out and see what it yields. Thanks.

Comment: THis is half way there, and this is what I have done. The link from David Khaykin which details the custom template within this is what I needed. THat solves my question, but as he has not written it as an answer I will mark this one as correct, as it is half way there and a good resource.